# C reading from file

Tags: c, file, printing

I am trying to write a code that reads a file and prints the chars from it. If the char is unreadable, it should print `?`. If there is errors on the file the code return `-1` else it returns the amount of chars read. Somehow this is not working properly cause I can't compile it.

```
int printfile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    int  i, c;
    char k = "?";

    while ((i = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) {
        c++;
        if(isprint(i)){
            printf("%c ", i);
        }
        else if (ferror(f)) return -1;
        else {
            printf("%c", k);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Should I reserve some space for this or something to make it work or is the code just wrong.

Comment: In what way is it not working properly?

Comment: "Somehow this is not working properly" is not a useful error description. Input, expected output, observed output. That's debugging 101, really. Also, your example code should compile into a program, i.e. have a `int main()` and all necessary includes.

Comment: First, you don't initialize `c`.  The value it starts at is indeterminate.  Second, you don't close the file with an `fclose()`.  Third, you never check that the original `fopen()` succeeded.

Comment: Your `printf("%c ", i);` prints an extra space; is that deliberate? Also, for single characters to `stdout` you could use `putchar( i );`, which is more efficient. `char k = "?";` is broken; `"?"` is of type `char []` with two elements, `'?'` and `'\0'`. You are assigning the address of the array to `char`...

Comment: `c` is undefined.  You have to initialize it.  The `ferror` check is unnecessary.  It will not be reached if there's an error, since `fgetc` will return `EOF` in that case.  Either eliminate the check, or else move it after the loop where it will actually do something.

Comment: "...cause I can't compile it." -- Seriously? **Seriously?** THAT is your edit? The compiler is **probably** telling you that it cannot make sense out of `FILE` (missing `#include <stdio.h>`), implicit declaration of `isprint()` (missing `#include <ctype.h>`), and missing `main()`. But not even including the actual compiler error message is just LAZY.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how i would implement PrintFile, hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int PrintFile(const char *filename);

int PrintFile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isprint(c))
        {
            fputc(c, stdout);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            fputc('?', stdout);
        }
    }

    if (ferror(file))
    {
        return -2;
    }

    return i;
}
```